# Can we merge the two "Do you have to like math?" questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, merge-questions

We have two separate questions asking whether you need to know/like/enjoy math to be a good programmer:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4680/is-it-possible-to-become-a-good-programmer-if-you-dont-like-math
  Asked in the Antedisciplining period
- [Do you have to be good at math to be a good programmer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89158/do-you-have-to-be-good-at-math-to-be-a-good-programmer#question)
  "Lovingly" migrated to us from Stack Overflow a few months ago

From my standpoint, these look like 1:1 duplicates and could be merged.

Is there any reason to have both of these questions? Is there some exclusivity to either question that I'm not seeing which would warrant having both around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These questions have now been merged:

> [Do you have to be good at math to be a good programmer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89158/do-you-have-to-be-good-at-math-to-be-a-good-programmer#question)

Answer (score 1):

I've spent some time reading the highly voted answers, and I think the questions should be merged. Questions:

1. Both have accepted answers. Which one gets the green shiny tick?
2. Several answers are substandard, iterating what's already been said on earlier questions, plain wrong, or otherwise bellow what we usually expect from answers. I'm assuming, since there's a total of 53 answers, some will be deleted?
3. Can we migrate both to Stack Overflow? I know *you* want to.

And how can we prevent the following Stack Overflow questions of getting migrated here?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157354/is-mathematics-necessary-for-programming
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137550/is-programming-a-subset-of-math
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500519/do-programmers-inherently-love-mathematics
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114191/how-do-i-think-about-math-in-programming
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876336/in-what-areas-of-programming-is-a-knowledge-of-mathematics-helpful
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436867/what-is-the-the-relation-between-programming-and-mathematics

I'm sure there are others. They seem off topic for Stack Overflow, and apart from the last one they are all open. Could you please be so kind as to point the Stack Overflow mods to them and ask them to close (if they are indeed off topic)? I'm a bit afraid to flag, in case that leads them here...

Comment: I pinged the SO mods to see if they can just close them outright, but in lieu of that, voting to close as off-topic on SO would short circuit any potential migration.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Yeap I know, but I'm far away from 3K rep on SO. Ordinarily I'd flag the questions, but I'm afraid that 10K users may misinterpret my flags and vote to migrate. I guess I could flag for moderation attention, but I thought assembling a kill list here would be a bit more representative that a 732 rep user compulsively flagging questions.